# Relationship between Product and Tag and its custom query

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, entity-relationship

I am trying to create a relationship between **Product** and **Tag**. Each Product can have **multiple** Tags and each Tag can be **assigned to multiple** Products. For example, a red t-shirt can have a "T-shirt" tag and a "Red color" tag, but likewise a white t-shirt can also have a "T-shirt" tag.

**Two questions:**

**First question:** Is it correct to use ManyToMany for this relationship?

**Second question:** How can I create a custom query if I want to get all the Tags of a particular product?
For example:
*GET /product/{productID}/tags* -> returns all tags of a product by its ID.

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String productName;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Tag> tag;
}

public class Tag{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String tagName;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Product> product;
}

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>{
    //There should be the custom query that returns all Tags that are assigned to specific product (by product ID)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first question, yes. Here's an [article](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) on @ManyToMany in Jpa. There you can find different ways to describe a many-to-many relationship to between your entities. In short, here's the approximate code:

In **Product**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
// the name of the intermediate table for many-to-many
name = "product_to_tag",
// the foreign key column in the intermediate table, that references 
// current entity(product)
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
// the foreign key column in the intermediate table, that references the 
// other entity(tag)
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
private List<Tag> tags;
```

In **Tag**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
private List<Product> products;
```

Answering your second question, there's a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452929/spring-data-jpa-many-to-many-query) which will help you. Here's the answer in short as well:

```
public interface TagRepository extends JpaRepository<Tag, Long> {
    @Query("select t from Tag t 
            join fetch t.products p 
            where p.id = :productId")
    List<Tag> getTags(@Param("productId") Long productId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have one more follow-up question. How can I assign a Product to a Tag? I tried tag.setProduct((List <Product>) product), but it doesnt work.

Comment: You can use cascade types persist and merge in @ManyToMany in Tag. Then you'll be able to add your product to the list of products in the tag: tag.getProducts().add(product). After saving/updating the tag the products will be automatically saved/updated.